# Prove a sequence converges without knowing its limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, elementary-functions

Let $(X_n)$ be the sequence with $X_1=2$ and $X_n=\sqrt{5X_{n-1} + 6}$ for all $n\ge 2$. How can you prove that it is convergent?

I know that its limit is $6$, but the question is how to rigorously prove its convergence without knowing it.

Comment: What criteria for the convergence of a sequence do you know?

Comment: ratio test, comparison test, root test, integral test...

Comment: Those are criteria for the convergence of _series_, we're dealing with a sequence here, so these don't apply. A sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence. But we're looking for something easier to check. So what theorems of the form "A sequence with this and that property is convergent" do you remember?

Comment: give me a hint please?

Comment: The Bolzano-Weierstraß theorem is somewhat pertinent.

Comment: BW theorem shows that it has a convergent subsequence...and?

Comment: And what additional property of the sequence would guarantee that it is convergent?

Comment: I tried, but have no idea

Comment: Flip through your book or notes to see whether you spot a theorem that looks pertinent.

Comment: One useful property of recursive sequences of the form $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ is that if $x_n \to L$ then we must necessarily have $f(L)=L$. This is quite useful for identifying candidates for limits of such sequences (in particular, it implies that the only possible limit of an iteration of your function is $6$). As you mentioned, it is easier to prove convergence if you know the limit.

Comment: thanks Ian. I remember this property now.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Step 1. Prove by induction that the sequence $$\left\{X_n\right\}_{n\geq1}$$ is increasing.

Step 2. Prove by induction that $$X_n\leq 6, \quad n\geq1.$$

Answer (score 3):

Forget $X_1=2$ and look at the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{5x+6}$$ if you think about it you know that on some interval the square function is above the line $x=y$ and after some point it will be below. If at some point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $f(x_0)>x_0$ then the sequence is increasing at that point, and if $f(x_0)<x_0$ it is deacreasing. Noticing that: $$f(x)<|x| \text{ for }x>6$$ $$f(x)>|x|\text{ for }-1<x<6$$
After the final note that $f(x)$ is increasing and as such doesn't have critical points and so will not go back and forth around the points $f(x)=x$ we get that starting at any point $X_1>-1$ will get you to have the limit $l=6$. If $-1<X_1<6$ it is increasing and if $X_1>6$ decreasing.

Comment: one comment too late